# Подкаталоги и каталоги с мп3 файлами в html файл(запись)

Tags: java, html, mp3

Вот собственно код, но метаданные записываются только тех файлов которые находятся в подкаталоге(возможно потому что он первый в корне папке) а метаданные файлов которые лежат в корне не записывает

```
public static void readFiles(File baseDirectory){

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if(baseDirectory.isDirectory()) {
                for (File fileloop : baseDirectory.listFiles()) {
                    if(fileloop.isFile()) {

                        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileloop);
                        ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
                        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                        Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                        ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
                        parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
                        input.close();
                        String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();
                        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Title: ") .append(metadata.get("title"));
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Artist: ").append(metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Album : ").append(metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Duration : ").append(toMinutes(metadata.get("xmpDM:duration")));
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Path : ");
                        sb.append("<a href= > ");
                        sb.append(fileloop.getAbsolutePath());
                        sb.append("</a>");
                        String result = sb.toString();
                        toHtml(result);
                    }
                    else{
                        readFiles(fileloop);
                    }
                }
            }
```

И вот метод `toHtml`

```
public static String  toHtml (String htmlData) throws IOException {

        File htmlTemplateFile = new File("D:\\music2\\HtmlMusic.html");
        String htmlString = FileUtils.readFileToString(htmlTemplateFile);
        htmlString = htmlString.replace("$body", htmlData);
        File newHtmlFile = new File("D:\\music2\\new.html");
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newHtmlFile,htmlString);
        return htmlString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекурсия у Вас имеется и все вложенные папки обходятся.
Проблема не в этом.
Проблема в том, что в html Вы записываете только результаты обхода последней директории.
И проблема конкретно с данной строкой

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newHtmlFile,htmlString);
```

Данная строка действительно записывает текст в указанный Вами файл. 
НО, начиная с версии 2.1 Apache IO, данный метод работает как для записи строки в начало файла, так и для записи строки в конец файла. По умолчанию данный метод записывает в начало файла. Для того чтобы записать строку в конец файла нужно передать в данный метод третий параметр `boolean append`. Соответственно, если передать туда `true`, то он будет каждый раз добавлять строку к уже имеющемуся контенту. А в Вашем случае Вы просто-напросто от папки к папке перезаписывали содержимое html-файла и до Вас доходили только результаты обхода последней папки.

Все, что Вам нужно это передать здесь `true` третьим параметром:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newHtmlFile, htmlString, true);
```

## Замечания

**Фильтрация**

При тестировании, на своих данных, когда у меня Ваш метод столкнулся с `flac`-файлом, парсер метаданных mp3 ушел в бесконечные раздумия.

Поэтому мой совет: отфильтровать файлы по расширению...

```
 if (fileloop.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
     //...Здесь обработка файлоы
 }
```

**Рекурсия**

Делать рекурсию вручную необязательно.
Например, `FileUtils`, который вы уже используете имеет метод `iterateFiles`, который может  вернуть Вам все файлы, включая вложенный папки, если его об этом попросить(передать boolean аргумент, который отвечает за наличие рекурсивного обхода).

Выглядит это примерно так:

```java
    File baseDirectory = new File("/path/to/root/directory/");
    Iterator<File> iterator = FileUtils.iterateFiles(baseDirectory, new String[]{"mp3"}, true);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        File file = iterator.next();
        // Здесь производятся все манипуляции с файлом
    }
```

В данном примере мы передали три аргумента в метод `iterateFiles`:

- `(File) baseDirectory` - корневая директория в которой ведется поиск файлов
- `new String[]{"mp3"}` - это массив, который выступает в качестве фильтра, состоящий из списка расширений(в данном случае нас интересует только "mp3")
- `true/false` - третий параметр, отвечает за то, нужно ли выполнять рекурсивный обход вложенных папок.

В итоге получится нечто вроде:

```
    File baseDirectory = new File("/path/to/root/directory/");
    Iterator<File> iterator = FileUtils.iterateFiles(baseDirectory, new String[]{"mp3"}, true);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        File file = iterator.next();

        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
        ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
        parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
        input.close();
        String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
        sb.append("<br>");
        sb.append("Title: ") .append(metadata.get("title"));
        sb.append("<br>");
        sb.append("Artist: ").append(metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
        sb.append("<br>");
        sb.append("Album : ").append(metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));
        sb.append("<br>");
        sb.append("Duration : ").append(toMinutes(metadata.get("xmpDM:duration")));
        sb.append("<br>");
        sb.append("Path : ");
        sb.append("<a href= > ");
        sb.append(file.getAbsolutePath());
        sb.append("</a>");
        String result = sb.toString();
        toHtml(result);
    }
```

В моем примере используется переменная `file` вместо переменной `fileloop`.

Comment: Окей спасибо, но что неправильно в моем случае?

Comment: @PaulFawkes, Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос ...в тексте вопроса. Вы просто извлекли список тех файлов, которые лежат непосредственно в `baseDirectory`.  И первой же строкой я потвердил это ваше утверждение: `Да, Вам необходимо рекурсивно получить все mp3 файлы.`. Я просто показал, как это можно сделать.

Comment: Так у меня есть не посредственно рекурсия посмотрите в else вызывается опять же этот метод readfiles, вывод в консоль происходит без проблем все файлы и в корне и в подкаталогах, а вот с записью в html проблемы, я выше скинул полный код

Comment: Даже в дебаге показывают что в result все мп3 записываются

Comment: Я так понял что, у меня проходит сначала по корневым файлам записывается в строку, после в подкаталог и перезаписывает эту строку и поэтому файлы только из подкаталога выводятся, как это можно исправить?

Comment: @Kioshilol, понял. Извиняюсь за невнимательность. Сейчас еще раз посмотрю.

Comment: @Kioshilol, протестил ваш код и нашел одну ошибку + есть одно замечание.

Comment: @Kioshilol, сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, жду у меня есть еще один вопрос если можно в чат?

Comment: @Kioshilol, да, конечно

Comment: ой к сожалению не могу слишком мало репутации(